# black pixels when save MRI dicom after applying lut

Tags: python, image-processing, pydicom, windowing, mri

I'm trying to apply LUT to MR images using following codes. the original dicom pixel intensities ranges from 0 to 4334 and the pixel intensities after applying LUT function ranges from 0 to 254. I need to preserve the metadata info for the resulted image. When I plot the resulted image, it displays correct but when I save the image, it is all black pixels. I know I need to change some meta data tags but I'm new to dicom image processing and couldn't figure out what is causing the problem.

```
def make_lut(dcm_data, width, center, p_i):
"""
LUT: look-up tables
VOI: volume of interest
"""
slope= 1.0
intercept= 0.0
min_px= int(np.amin(dcm_data))
max_px= int(np.amax(dcm_data))
lut= [0] * (max_px + 1)
invert= False
if p_i == "MONOCHROME1":
    invert= True
else:
    center = (max_px - min_px) - center
for px_value in range(min_px, max_px):
    lut_value = px_value * slope + intercept
    voi_value= (((lut_value - center) / width + 0.5) * 255.0)
    clamped_value= min(max(voi_value, 0), 255)
    if invert: 
        lut[px_value] = round(255 - clamped_value)
    else:
        lut[px_value] = round(clamped_value)
return lut

def apply_lut(pixels_in, lut):
pixels= pixels_in.flatten()
pixels_out= [0] * len(pixels)
for i in range (0, len(pixels)):
    pixel= pixels[i]
    if pixel > 0:
        pixels_out[i] = int(lut[pixel])
return np.reshape(pixels_out, (pixels_in.shape[0], pixels_in.shape[1]))

# apply the function
idx= 30
ds= pydicom.dcmread(dcm_files[idx])
raw_pixels= dcm_data.pixel_array
if dcm_data.WindowWidth != '' and dcm_data.WindowCenter != '':
    window_width = dcm_data.WindowWidth
    window_center = dcm_data.WindowCenter

lut = make_lut(raw_pixels, window_width, window_center, dcm_data.PhotometricInterpretation)
dcm_default_windowing = apply_lut(raw_pixels, lut)

# save the result
ds.PixelData = dcm_default_windowing.tobytes()
ds.save_as("test_luted.dcm")
```

Comment: Why would you do this? You are essentially destroying information from the DICOM file. Any DICOM viewer will know how to apply the LUT, so if you want to change it, you just have to adapt WindowWidth/WindowCenter in the DICOM file.

Comment: The dicom images are very dark and I'm trying to improve the images for training a deep learning model

Comment: In that case the better strategy would probably be to adapt the part that reads the image from the DICOM file before it is fed into the network, so that the image with the applied LUT is used in the model without having to change the original DICOM file (which could be cumbersome).

Comment: Thank you! yes, that was my thought and I added the lut function into my DataGenerator as part of other preprocessing steps.